# Libgdx. Как настроить ввод текста в android и уведомления

Tags: java, android, libgdx, клавиатура, push-уведомления

Какие есть методы в libgdx для ввода текста с виртуальной клавиатуры? Какие есть методы или классы для создания push-уведомлений?

Answer (score 0):

Для ввода текста используется класс TextField. Когда TextField получит фокус, то клавиатура должна появиться автоматически.
Что касается пуш-уведомлений, то их надо созавать в модуле android.